# Codeigniter Login Functionality

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Hi I am using codeigniter, Here I have a major defect which is when login for first its not logged in but when why refresh the page and loggedin for second time it is login successfully, And this is my model:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, this error because you check `$this->session->userdata('login_type')` before define this item in session, so solution is to reorder your code as the following:

```
if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'admin') {
    $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'admin');
}

if ($this->session->userdata('login_type') == 'admin') {
    redirect('/Dashboard');
}
```

Comment: i think this is the solution, first time you check value not defined in session, so that you should replace code as i discussed before

Comment: thank u soo much for your help and another thing is if there is error occured i want to redirects the page to home page could u tell me how to right that logic

Comment: You can either do this in each controller by wrapping function with try catch statement ...snd in catch you will redirect ...or you can use route array in config folder to set route for error page